# How to detect updated products using scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So basicly I want that everytime this website is updated with new crypto coins, it sends an email with the new name of the crypto coin , this is the website https://coinmarketcap.com/fr/new/
and here is the code :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


headers={"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}

def func(URL):
    l1=[]
    l2=[]
    page=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    info1=soup.find_all('div',class_='h7vnx2-1 bFzXgL')
    for i in info1: 
        table=i.find_all('table',class_="h7vnx2-2 deceFm cmc-table")
        for i in table:
            tbody=i.find_all('tbody')
            for i in tbody:
                tr=i.find_all('tr')
                for i in tr: 
                    td=i.find_all('td',{'style':'text-align:left'})[1]
                    td2=i.find_all('td',{'style':'text-align:right'})[6].get_text()
                    l1.append(td2)
     
                    for i in td:
                        coin=i.find_all('div',class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 dNOTPP')
                        for i in coin:
                            coin_name=i.find('p',class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT').get_text()
                            l2.append(coin_name)
                    

    for i in range (0,len(l1)): 
        x=l2[i]+' | ' +l1[i]
        print(x)
```

Comment: what is the problem? do you get error message ? alalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you will have to use loop (with sleep) to run this function every few seconds. OR you should check [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) for programmers - to get data as JSON. It may also have methods to use `websocket` - and then server may send  data when they change.

Comment: there is `Search` at the top of this page. If you search `coinmarketcap` then you should find many similar questions for `coinmarketcap`

Comment: yoou may need global list with coin names and `func()` should check if `coin_name` already exist in this list.